# Maven does not resolve parent's revision if in another repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

Im using mvn 3.6.1 and Im unable to get ${revision} resolved correctly for the following scenario:

Parent repo (separate repo):
top/pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.x</groupId>
<artifactId>top</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
```

mvn -Drevision=1.0.0 clean deploy  # installs fine in local .m2 and deploys fine to nexus

Derived Child repo (separate repo)

```
<groupId>com.x</groupId>
<artifactId>child</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>top</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version> <!-- This is not resolving -->
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

mvn -Drevision=1.0.0 clean install
throws error Non-resolvable parent pom error:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for com.x:child:${revision}: Could not transfer artifact com.x:top:pom:${revision} from/to nexus  ($nexusUrl): Failed to transfer file ${nexusUrl}/com/x/top/$%7Brevision%7D/top-$%7Brevision%7D.pom with status code 400 and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 12, column 1
```

as its looking for literally "com.x:top:pom:${revision}" instead of thev alue. The same error occurs even if I remove the tag .

If I use the following parent with a local relativePath, it works fine:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>top</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <relativePath>../top</relativePath>
</parent>
```

In summary, if using parent:${revision} with no relativePath, mvn always tries to resolve ${revision} literally instead of the supplied -D value.

I also tried variations like mvn -Dparent.revision=1.0.0, didnt work either.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: this is unfortunately not fully supported by maven yet (maven 3.6.3). you can find details here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-935

Comment: Same problem, not resolved yet